# Why Doesn't Regex give a chance to input data?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, textbox, mask

I have a event which doesn't give a any opportunity to input data in  TextBox. When I'm trying to input data in Textbox, then Textbox doesn't give to do it:

```
private void Login_textbox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textbox1.Text, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$"))
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

I just want to input data in TextBox which isn't digit or any symbols.

Comment: What language are you trying to code in?  Please add the appropriate tag.

Comment: Your regular expression requires the text to contain _at least one_ character in `a-zA-Z`, so when the box is empty, it won't allow you to enter anything! Change the + to a *.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following code

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(e.KeyChar.ToString() , @"^[a-zA-Z]+$")) 
         e.Handled = true;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot, Nitesh Kumar Lal, it works out!
My programm works very well!:)

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are using c#.

Then steps you need to follow :

1) Set causesValidation property of your textbox to true

2) Set event listeners for causes validation

```
myTextBox1.Validating +=
  new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(myTextBox1_Validating);
myTextBox1.Validated += 
  new System.EventHandler(myTextBox1_Validated);
```

3) Implement these event hadler functions

```
private void myTextBox1_Validating(object sender,System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{        
   if(!CheckIfTextBoxNumeric(myTextBox1))
   {
       myLabel.Text =  "Has to be numeric";
       e.Cancel = true;
   }
}
private void myTextBox1_Validated(object sender,System.EventArgs e)
{
   myLabel.Text = "Validated first control";          
}
```

If you instead want to use maskedTextBox refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms234064(v=vs.80).aspx